# How to empty temp folder at the end of each loop in R?

Tags: r

I am running a model in R.
I would like to know how to empty the temp folder.

For example:`C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp`

at the end of each loop in R.

Comment: `unlink` with `recursive=TRUE`?

Answer (score 1):

```
file.remove(list.files("C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Temp",full.names = T))
```

This should help.